# Source code analyzer tool (similar to RATS)

Tags: code-analysis

[RATS](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/codetools/rats.shtml) is a C, C++, Perl, PHP and Python source code analyzer by Fortify.

The link used to be a [fortify.com address](https://www.fortify.com/ssa-elements/threat-intelligence/rats.html). However, now it redirects to hp.com, and the webmaster broke the link. And searching HP results in lots of irrelevant hits, like articles about mice and rats. (Webmasters should lose money for each link they break).

Is RATS still freely available? Or has Fortify replaced it with another free tool? If its available, could someone provide a link? If not, then what's a good alternative?

Comment: I've edited the question to try and make it more relevant. People would also be able to help you find alternatives easier if you add a list of features that you require in a code analyzer.

Comment: Most people don't know RATS. Please explain all features you want. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a link to the source code: https://rough-auditing-tool-for-security.googlecode.com/files/rats-2.4.tgz I have no experience with RATS or this link.

Answer (score 2):

As Ira Baxter pointed out in the comments, the source for RATS is still available at https://code.google.com/archive/p/rough-auditing-tool-for-security/downloads

A binary for Windows 32bit is available at the URL above.

The source code has received no maintenance since 2014, and now that Google Code is read-only the place to watch might be https://github.com/andrew-d/rough-auditing-tool-for-security (none of the forks are active though)

Answer (score 0):

Flawfinder, RATS and [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) are good security static analysis tools for C/C++. they are used to pick out vulnerabilities in source code without actually running the code.

This makes them more portable, but also creates a lot of false positives when looking for actual vulnerabilities in code. They are used more for screening potential vulnerabilities than definitively identifying them.

There is now a [GitHub page for RATS](https://github.com/andrew-d/rough-auditing-tool-for-security) that has the source code and lists installation instructions.